# Checkstyle to check that a certain class is only used inside a certain package or subpackage

Tags: java, checkstyle

We have a utility class : JsonRequestBuilder

I only want that this class is used inside "datamanager" packages (or subpackages), and not inside ui code and so on.

So  JsonRequestBuilder may be used in packages like

```
be.knarf.datamanager
be.knarf.datamanager.special it is also ok
```

But not in packages like

```
be.knarf.screens
```

Anyone knows how to do this ? Can this be done with one of the regex checks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Checkstyle, this is commonly achieved using the [ImportControl](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#ImportControl) check. It basically lets you specify which imports are allowed in which packages, and checks that on your codebase.

One caveat is that it will not find fully qualified references to classes in the code, it only checks imports. But that is still quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not answering with checkstyle, but can't you put the `JsonRequestBuilder` in the `be.knarf.datamanager` package and remove the public modifier from the class, that way it should be package private.

Comment: The package tree may be too complicated to allow it

Comment: That doesn't work, package private means it's also not visible in sub-packages.

Comment: JsonRequestBuilder is actually a class from a self written library, used by multiple projects of ours. Inside all those projects there is a datamanager package. And JsonRequestBuilder should be only used inside those packages (or subpackages of those) So like Mad Physicist says, the package tree is too complicated.